# Eclipse PyDev : __module_not_in_the_pythonpath__

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pydev

**CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)**

**openjdk 11 2018-09-25**

**Python 3.6.9**

**Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)**

**PyDev 7.0.3.2018.11082356**

I'm new to PyDev and pretty new to Python.

I have a Python project composed of several dozen Eclipse projects/plugins.

When I hover a Python method in our code to get more information or use tools on it I get this error message:

```
Found at: __module_not_in_the_pythonpath__
```

[image]

**Each Eclipse project was imported this way:**

Import > Git > Projects From Git > Existing Local Repository > Select A Repository ( choosing all the projects in the repo, then moving on to "finish": )

**Each Eclipse project has:**

1. "src" directory containing *.java files
2. "util" directory containing *.py files
3. an autogenerated .project file ( underpopulated )
4. an autogenerated .pydevprodject file ( underpopulated )

[image]

**The .project file I have:**

[image]

**The .pydevproject file I have:**

[image]

Obviously, from this [FAQ](http://pydev.org/faq.html#ImportExistingSources) those .project and .pydevproject files need to be updated.

The "util" dir is the parent directory for all of the projects *.py files.  It does not have an `__init__.py` file.  Do I need to put one in the "util" dir to fix this error?  Will a single `__init__.py` file in the "util" dir will that be enough for Python and Eclipse to find all of the *.py files in the subdirectories beneath it?

Comment: Hi @Steve, is this project on a public repo that I can take a look to offer a good suggestion based on your use-case? -- maybe http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#ImportExistingSources can help you there too... Also, can you provide a screenshot with the error? (please show the editor and the PyDev Package Explorer expanded to that file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the module wasn't really imported as a PyDev project (because the project root was not shown in the screenshot).

If that's the case, you can convert your project to a PyDev project by right-clicking it and choosing `PyDev > Set as PyDev project`.

After having it as a PyDev project you have to set each folder that's in the PYTHONPATH as a source folder (note that just the entry in the PYTHONPATH must be set this way, not subfolders).

You can either right-click the folder and choose `PyDev > Set as source folder` or if you have too many entries you can create a script to generate your `.pydevproject` files with those entries as explained in http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#ImportExistingSources.

Note that you should not add those folders to the interpreter PYTHONPATH (the folders added to the PYTHONPATH in the interpreter are shared across all projects, whereas the folders added as source folders are valid only for one project -- if you have multiple projects PyDev will compose the final PYTHONPATH based on the interpreter + project + referenced projects).

Comment: I updated my main post per our conversation, to make things more clear.  I added new information and new questions.

Comment: You don't need `__init__.py` files in folders if you're using Python 3 (you only need `__init__.py` files if you're using Python 2).

What you need to do here is set the source folder.

From your screenshot, I believe that you want to set `utility/common_static/base/python` as a source folder (i.e.: right-click that folder and choose: PyDev > Set as Source folder). That should be enough to make things work (if it still doesn't work, please report back).

Comment: That worked.  I made a script to update all of my .pydevproject files.  Lots of good stuff is now available.  Thank you.